# How do I cast a pointer to a C++ struct with data members to a pointer to a C++ struct which has no data members?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

How do I cast a pointer to a C++ struct with data members  to a pointer to a C++ struct which has no data members such as:
struct libusb_device_handle?

For example , On windows 7 , I would like to  cast a C++ pointer to   HRAWINPUT   to a C++ pointer  to a   C++ struct which has no data member such as libusb_device_handle

```
   for (size_t idx = 0; idx < count; ++idx) { 
        libusb_device *device = list[idx]; 
        libusb_device_descriptor desc = { 0 }; 
        rc = libusb_get_device_descriptor(device, &desc); 
        if (desc.idVendor == MY_VID && 
        desc.idProduct    ==MY_PID)                                                              {              


            libusb_device_handle *handle; 
            libusb_open(device, &handle);                                                                               libusb_claim_interface(handle, 0); 
            return (HRAWINPUT *)&handle; 
         } 
    }
```

The reason I want to do this is shown here:

I have already  opened the CH Products VM Desktop joystick device via libusb_open(). Then,  I would like to do some magic (meaning polling for events) such as invoking GetRawInputData() on the casted version of pointer to libusb_device_handle so as to record the x and y coordinates when we move the joystick vigorously.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The same way you do any other cast, but to be legal they'd still have to be part of the same inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: One line of code is better than 1000 words...

Comment: Show what you are trying to do.

Comment: @BoBTFish, How  do I make struct libusb_device_handle {} a parent of HRAWINPUT? I change the header file for libusb.h but not the header file for HRAWINPUT. Thanks.

Comment: `How do I make struct libusb_device_handle {} a parent of HRAWINPUT` You cannot. `I change the header file for libusb.h` Don't do that. *Show what you are trying to do*.

Comment: @n.m.     Here is an excerpt of what I am trying to do.                                                      for (size_t idx = 0; idx < count; ++idx) {
  libusb_device *device = list[idx];
  libusb_device_descriptor desc = { 0 };

  rc = libusb_get_device_descriptor(device, &desc);
 
  printf("Vendor:Device = %d %d %d %d\n", desc.idVendor, desc.idProduct, desc.iManufacturer, desc.iProduct);
  if (desc.idVendor == MY_VID && desc.idProduct == MY_PID){
   libusb_device_handle *handle;

   libusb_open(device, &handle);
   libusb_claim_interface(handle, 0);
   return (HRAWINPUT *)&handle;
  }
 }

Comment: Please use the edit button and put it in the question, properly formatted. Comments are not a good place for this.

Comment: No, a cast makes no sense here. You cannot magically transform a device descriptor into an input event, these are totally different things.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just cast pointers to structures and assume things will work. By casting a pointer you are simply telling the compiler for example that a pointer to say a `double` should be considered instead a pointer to an `std::string` instance. This is normally a **very** bad idea and will not convert the `double` into a `std::string`.

In the specific you should follow the Microsoft API specifications for raw input reading from a Joystick; a tutorial can be found for example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/185522/Using-the-Raw-Input-API-to-Process-Joystick-Input).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tested and debugged Alexander Bocken's tutorial for using raw input to read from a Joystick and it has bugs.